# Finding a formula for a given series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble figuring out how to evaluate:

$$\sum _{j = 1}^{n} j!j$$

I've tried plugging in numbers and looking for a pattern and I've also tried to find a general form like:

$$n=1:$$ $$ 1*1 = 1 = n^2$$ $$n =2:$$ $$ 1*1 + 1*2*2 = 5  = (n-1)^2 + (n-1)(n)^2$$

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: $j!j = (j+1)!-j!$

Comment: Try adding one to the partial sums, see if you find a pattern.